# How to copy data from a cell in Excel to a webpage text field?

Tags: html, vba, excel

I want to develop some tool which will directly copy and paste contents of an Excel cell to a text field of a particular webpage.

I don't have any idea about computer programming. I have a little knowledge of Excel VBA.

Please  guide me in following aspects:

1. How to open a particular webpage from a button click through Excel.
2. How to auto-fill data into text fields of webpage?
3. How to automatically press a button on webpage through Excel.

Please note I don't have any details about that webpage.

Comment: I think you are going to have to do a bit of background research and learning to make this possible. I'm not sure you will find many SO users willing to just write a project like this for you from scratch. The way this would usually work would be for you to have a go and post specific questions as and when you get stuck including details of what you have tried. There are a number of starting points you take to get some basic web development knowledge. W3C provide tutorials, I would start with the HTML: http://www.w3schools.com/html/.

Comment: Once you have got the basics I would recommend looking at something like the Udacity web development course for more detail: https://www.udacity.com/course/cs253

Comment: I am working on a firmware part of a wi-fi enabled product.The server and website part is going to be developed by third party firm.To taste our firmware we have to write payload in a text field of webpage.As in most cases this is time crucial project and we have very less time to do this.

Comment: Up til now I am able to write a excel macro to form various payloads as per necessity..but I have to manually copy and paste the payload from excel cell to text field of webpage.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using an existing tool such as [curl or wget](http://daniel.haxx.se/docs/curl-vs-wget.html). Both can be used to fetch and post data to websites and they work great with scripts.