# How to enter data into IE webpage form from excel cell

Tags: html, vba, excel, internet-explorer

I did a lot of searching prior to this without success.  Links searched included at least the links at the bottom of this post.  PLEASE HELP.

The website in question is https://vcheck.ttc.lacounty.gov/proptax.php?page=main and you get to the relevant APN input screen after beating a CAPTCHA and click the "Property Tax Inquiry/One-Time Payment" link.  Then you can enter an APN number.

I was able to piece all the code to get me to the webpage, but none of my attempts to enter in an APN number from my excel sheet are working.  Code is below.  The 1234567891 is merely an example, I really want it to pull from Sheet 1 and whatever cell I choose.  I found code to do that piece, but the web page never populates :(

```
Private Sub cmdAPNenter_Click()

Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

ie.Visible = True

ie.Navigate "https://vcheck.ttc.lacounty.gov/proptax.php?page=main" 
'we are going to los angeles property tax page

Do

DoEvents

Loop Until ie.ReadyState = 4

'ie READYSTATE has 5 different status codes, here we are using status 4:

'Uninitialized = 0

'Loading = 1

'Loaded = 2

'Interactive = 3

'Complete = 4

Call ie.Document.GetElementByID("theform").SetAttribute("value", "1234567891")


Do

DoEvents

Loop Until ie.ReadyState = 3

Do

DoEvents

Loop Until ie.ReadyState = 4

End Sub
```

[VBA to Enter Data Online and Submit Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17409613/vba-to-enter-data-online-and-submit-form)
[How to copy data from a cell in Excel to a webpage text field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18614782/how-to-copy-data-from-a-cell-in-excel-to-a-webpage-text-field)
[Input text into html input box using vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20611714/input-text-into-html-input-box-using-vba)

Comment: Take a look at here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17409613/vba-to-enter-data-online-and-submit-form

Comment: There are three  fields and a submit button on that page, so you need a bit more coding here.

Comment: Hi, I realize there's a bit more coding, but I can't even get my code to post into the fields.  That's the issue.  Do I have the wrong ID?